# Angular JS 2. Как загрузить изображение в BLOB, byte array

Tags: angularjs

Как загрузить изображение и отправить на сервер, в БД, в байтах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример моего кода:

```
uploadAvatar(e: any) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    fileReader.onloadend = (e: any) => {
        this.avatar = fileReader.result;
        this.saveAvatar(this.dataURItoBlob(fileReader.result), fileName);
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}

saveAvatar(image: Blob, name: string) {
    this.userService.saveAvatar(image, name).subscribe();
}

private dataURItoBlob(dataURI): Blob {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var blob = new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
    return blob;
}
```

uploadAvatar - вешаеться на (change) в  после чего с помощю dataURItoBlob приобразовывает dataURI в Blob, после чего через сервис отправляю на сервер: метод saveAvatar. 
Пример сервиса:

```
saveAvatar(image, name ): Observable<any> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('avatar', image, name);
  return this.http.post(url, formData);
}
```

Отправка на сервер осуществляешься через POST из сервиса HttpClient, первым параметром принимает URL, 2 пераметр экземпляр FormData в который добавлена наша картинка.

Примеры кода сделаны на Angular 5.2.3